# preg_replace() containing $(abc) not working

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to bold specific string content using `preg_replace()` function. The `$()` string got bolded successfully.

```
          <?php 
         $text=preg_replace("/$()/","<b>$()</b>","$(), you can");
          echo $text;
          ?>
```

But as soon as I added some word inside the parentheses the function stopped working. Nevertheless, the function did not throw any error either.

```
         <?php  
         $text=preg_replace("/$(abc)/","<b>$(abc)</b>","$(abc), you can");
          echo $text;
          ?>
```

Could anybody explain this please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the first output correct in any way? It outputs nothing close to what you describe you want.

Comment: check your regex on http://www.regex101.com , seriously, it's well worth it. `preg_replace` will only do what you tell it!

Comment: @Anonymous i not understand what u mean......

Comment: @ArchitSaxena It outputs `'$(), you can<b>$()</b>'`

Comment: @Anonymous ....yes exactly,  but when i add something inside the parenthesis .....say $(abc) the same not works??????

Comment: @ArchitSaxena Did you not want the output to be `'<b>$()</b>, you can'`? I would suggest you make sure to debug and research more thoroughly when asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regex ["worked"](https://regex101.com/r/wG9sL9/1) because it matched an empty string at the end of the input, and replaced with `<b>$()</b>`.

[image]

You need to escape special symbols:

```
'/\$\(abc\)/'
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/LtaJVo)

```
$text=preg_replace("/\\$\\(abc\\)/","<b>$(abc)</b>","In place of $(abc), you can");
```

Output: `In place of <b>$(abc)</b>, you can`

Comment: I added the explanation. Actually, `(` and `)` were not literal brackets, just a capturing group.